# How to change DCOM settings with the command line

Tags: windows, com, command-prompt

I have to set DCOM permissions to the Network Services user using the command line. I have already googled it to no avail.
Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my poor english.

[image: Here is what i want to do]

Comment: Have you found a way to do this with CMD? Thx

Answer (score 1):

The only thing doing this I've ever been able to find was "dcomperm sample" which is [included into Microsoft SDK](https://serverfault.com/a/333773/101). When we needed altering permissions of a DCOM server for our service I've read that code and reimplemented the necessary parts in C# - the original code is working and quite clear, good for inspiration. The bottom line is there's nothing better than that sample for solving this task.

Comment: Has anything changed after all these years?